# How to extract a word that occurs between two keywords on a line?

Tags: text-processing, csh

Suppose I have a code mentioned below.

```
module dut#(parameter type tp =int, tp x = 12 ) (int r , reg [7:0] rg);
endmodule

module mid (int r, reg [7:0] rg);
endmodule

module bin (int z, logix s);
endmodule

module med;
endmodule
```

I want to extract the words `dut`, `mid`, `bin` and `med`, characterized by being the words after the keyword `module` and before the symbol `#`, `(` or `;`, whichever comes first.

I want to accomplish this using only a `csh` script. Which regex can be used for that purpose?

Comment: so you also want `med` in `module med;` according to the answer you accepted?

Comment: Yes , I also want to include module med because , this will add another condition i.e semicolon (;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by saying `only using csh script`. Can you use standard programs? If yes then:

The simplest solution **for me** is using `grep` and `awk`.

```
grep "module \w*" -o filename | awk '{print $2}'
dut
mid
bin
```

Comment: If you cannot use `grep` or `awk` for some reason then I will try to find out other solution.

Comment: Alex , i can't extract a word directly by naming grep dut, mid or bin. It must be generalized because  name may differ. so the only thing fixed in a test cases is module , #, ( . so I want access between module & # or ( .

Comment: So it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Using (gnu)grep:

```
 grep -Po 'module +\K\w+' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `sed`:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^module +([^ (#;]+) *[#(;].*$/\1/p' filename
dut
mid
bin
```

This will extract the module name by replacing (`s`) the entire line with the expression found in the parentheses.

Currently,

- it looks for lines that start with "module" (`^module`), followed by one or more spaces ( `+`), and then followed by a string of one or more characters *that are not space, `(` or `#`, `;`*. This string is placed in a "capture group" because its specification `[^ (#;]+` is placed inside parentheses `( ... )`. The regular expression then forces zero or more spaces ( `*`), then either a `#`, a `(` or a `;` (`[#(;]`), and then any number of any character up to the end of the line (`.*$`), for a line to be considered a match.
- If a match is found, the replacement is printed (`p`), but the `-n` option ensures that lines without match are not printed by default.

If you want to learn more about regular expressions, take a look [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) e.g.

Answer (score 0):

with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'[ \t#(;]+' '/^module/{ print $2}' infile
dut
mid
bin
med
```

print second field where separators are one of  Space /Tab`\t`/`#`/`;` or `(` characters and ignore repetition (`+`)